# Should cloning an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment remove SSH source restrictions?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I clone (using `eb clone`) an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment that has in inbound SSH rule, any restrictions on the source for that rule are removed.

For example, if I have restricted the source to "My IP" on the original environment, it becomes "Anywhere" for the clone.

Is this the intended behavior? Should cloning an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment remove SSH source restrictions (in the clone)?

Comment: @BMW: I'm asking whether `eb clone` should have this behavior.